# Trying to find one word on several variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables

I'm asking to MySQL if one of the fields has certain word contained in the $Especialidad variable. I'm asking if that word are contained in one of several variables. I have the following code but that part doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM   wp_consultte
WHERE  genero = '$Sexo'
        OR estadocivil = '$Civil'
           AND ( opc = '$Especialidad'
                  OR opd = '$Especialidad'
                  OR osp = '$Especialidad'
                  OR comisiones = '$Especialidad'
                  OR regulaciones = '$Especialidad'
                  OR programas = '$Especialidad'
                  OR regimenes = '$Especialidad'
                  OR ordenamiento = '$Especialidad'
                  OR negociadores = '$Especialidad'
                  OR logistica = '$Especialidad' )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a "reversed" `IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   wp_consultte
WHERE  genero = '$Sexo'
OR estadocivil = '$Civil'
AND '$Especialidad' in (opc, opd, osp, comisiones, ...)
```

Note that if any of the columns are nullable, you should wrap those columns in `ifnull(col,'')` to ensure there are no null values in the list, otherwise you won't get a match (it's just the way SQL works).

Note: Caution is advised when used `OR` without brackets! `AND` takes precedence and it's easy to code your condition incorrectly without brackets.

#### Edited:

If you want to use `LIKE` instead of an exact match, you can do this:

```
WHERE concat(opc, opd, osp, comisiones, ...) LIKE concat('%','$Especialidad','%')
```

This turns the variable into an open-ended like pattern, which is matched anywhere in the strings. To be completely strict, you should insert a spacer character between the columns, otherwise it can match crossing from the end of one the the start of the next.

Comment: It appears like if all the fields had that variable :(

Comment: ¿If i wanted to use something like "LIKE" here? AND '$Especialidad' in (opc, opd, osp, comisiones, ...)

Comment: @user1515538 This will only work for exact matches. Or like, there is also a trick like this, but it's a bit more complicated - you use `concat()` on both sides and reverse the usual order of operands. See edited answer

Comment: Thanks, I used again the first code and replace OR estadocivil for AND estadocivil. It works partially, beacuse it appears that the LIKE doesn't work and search for the exact case. For example there is a field called ECONOMÃA,SEMARNAT but when I search "SEMARNAT" nothing happens with the LIKE